# Difficulty installing Magento2

Tags: nginx, magento2

I am having an issue with Nginx and Magento2. No matter what I do I get a 403. I am using wsl2/windows.

Nginx default pages display fine.
In set up the nginx site available configs and executed.

Is there something specific I should be doing with server name under nginx config… I am so confused